# How to embed Twitch channel (video + chat) using React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitch, twitch-api

Hello I'm creating a web app for myself and trying to use the [Twitch Embedded API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed#embedding-everything) to display Twitch streams and the chat within my web page. I'm not sure how to handle this I have some experience with React JS but definitely not this.

They provide an HTML but I have no idea how to make it work on my app:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- Add a placeholder for the Twitch embed -->
    <div id="twitch-embed"></div>

    <!-- Load the Twitch embed JavaScript file -->
    <script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>

    <!-- Create a Twitch.Embed object that will render within the "twitch-embed" element -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
        width: 854,
        height: 480,
        channel: "monstercat",
        // Only needed if this page is going to be embedded on other websites
        parent: ["embed.example.com", "othersite.example.com"]
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Since I didn't understand this bit I went to try and just get the video at least, this is the code they provide, but I have not manage it to make it work so far:

```
<iframe
    src="https://player.twitch.tv/?<channel, video, or collection>&parent=streamernews.example.com"
    height="<height>"
    width="<width>"
    allowfullscreen="<allowfullscreen>">
</iframe>
```

I did the following and got this result:

```
<Box mb={3} sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center',  mr: 2}}>

<CardMedia  
component = "iframe" 
src="https://player.twitch.tv/?<StreamerName>&parent=localhost"
title = 'Faker stream' 
controls/>

</Box>
```

[image]

Or this

[image]

This is the [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-mountain-esjje?file=/src/App.js) I have created. I saw other resources/questions/answers and they are a bit outdated which is why I created this new question.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was wondering how to do this I got the video one working. I'll update it again if I get the HTML one with chat + video working.

**JUST VIDEO**

```
   <Box mb={3} sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center',  mr: 2,  color: "white"}}>
       <CardMedia  
       component = "iframe" 
       src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=faker&parent=localhost"
       height = "800"
       title = 'Faker stream' 
       controls/>
   </Box>
```